# Case in Where SQL

Tags: postgresql

I want to make a new temporary column, which contains sum of 'modal'. But I got a problem like this, and I don't know what it means.

```
    begin;
SELECT kios.nama_kios, jenis_kios as jenis, 'modal' as TempField
FROM  kios
JOIN dimiliki on dimiliki.id_kios=kios.id_kios
JOIN pemilik on pemilik.id_pemilik=dimiliki.id_pemilik
WHERE nama_pemilik='lili' 
AND 
    CASE    WHEN jenis_kios='makanan' then 5
        WHEN jenis_kios='mainan' then 6
        WHEN jenis_kios='pakaian' then 6
        WHEN jenis_kios='sepatu' then 7
        WHEN jenis_kios='buku' then 8
        WHEN jenis_kios='elektronik' then 10
        ELSE 9
     modal END;
```

[image]

Comment: Which DBMS is this for?

Answer (score 3):

You can't define a column in the `WHERE` clause. You can - and only do that - in the `SELECT` list.

Besides that, the alias of the column should go **after** the `END`:

```
SELECT 
    kios.nama_kios, jenis_kios AS jenis,
    CASE    WHEN jenis_kios = 'makanan' THEN 5
            WHEN jenis_kios = 'mainan' THEN 6
            WHEN jenis_kios = 'pakaian' THEN 6
            WHEN jenis_kios = 'sepatu' THEN 7
            WHEN jenis_kios = 'buku' THEN 8
            WHEN jenis_kios = 'elektronik' THEN 10
            ELSE 9
    END AS modal           -- or Tempfield
FROM  
    kios
  JOIN dimiliki ON dimiliki.id_kios = kios.id_kios
  JOIN pemilik ON pemilik.id_pemilik = dimiliki.id_pemilik
WHERE
    nama_pemilik = 'lili' ;
```

You could also simplify a bit the `CASE` expression, since you have only equality comparisons and only against the same expression (`jenis_kios`):

```
    CASE jenis_kios   
        WHEN 'makanan' THEN 5
        WHEN 'mainan' THEN 6
        WHEN 'pakaian' THEN 6
        WHEN 'sepatu' THEN 7
        WHEN 'buku' THEN 8
        WHEN 'elektronik' THEN 10
        ELSE 9
    END AS modal           -- or Tempfield
```